# __autoload with namespace class gives fatal error for file not found

Tags: php, class, oop, namespaces, autoload

I was going through the `__autoload` feature that `PHP` provides.

However this is the `index.php` I have:-

```
define('app_path', realpath('../'));

$paths = array(
        app_path, get_include_path());
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));

function __autoload($classname)
{
    $filename = str_replace('\\', '/', $classname.'.php');
    require_once $filename;
}

use \engine\controllers as Controllers;

$data = new Controllers\base(); // This one is line no. 25 (Here is error)
echo $data->mind('Hi');
```

And this one as my `base.php`:-

```
 namespace controllers;
 class base {
    public function __construct() {
        echo __CLASS__ . '<br/>';
        echo __NAMESPACE__;
    }

    public function mind($myname)
    {
        echo $myname;
    }
 }
```

and throws this error:

[image]

My directory structure is as follows:

`app -> engine -> controller -> base.php`

`app -> index.php`

I am not sure whats wrong is happening. I am just learning how to use `namespace` and `__autoload`

I also tried `spl_autoload_register` but did not success. Kindly suggest.

**EDIT:1**

Also, if i want to replace it with spl_autoload_register how that can be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but worth a try:

In base.php, change to `namespace engine\controllers;` on line 1.

And in index.php, change to `use engine\controllers as Controllers;` (remove leading backslash) on line 23.

Comment: OMG you are darling :* That is why engineers are God borns.... you guys can smell every letter of codes.

Comment: Also, if i want to replace it with `spl_autoload_register` how that can be implemented.